# Argument Type Mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

Line  5 of the code gives me an argument type mistmatch. Help me please?

```
 Sub ImportBPlans()
Dim BPlan, FullHTML, URL1, Cut1 As String
Dim FO, LO, Other1 As Integer

URL1 = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=AAPL+Profile"
FullHTML = GetHTML(URL1)
BPlan = "&nbsp;</th></tr></table><p>"
FO = InStr(FullHTML, BPlan) + Len(BPlan)
LO = InStr(FO, FullHTML, "<")
Cut1 = Left(FullHMTML, LO)
Cut1 = Right(Cut1, FO - LO)


WB5.Cells(1, 1).Value = Cut1



End Sub

Function GetHTML(URL As String) As String
    Dim HTML As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .Send
        GetHTML = .ResponseText
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing an expected **HTMLDocument** with its string contents.

```
Sub ImportBPlans()
    Dim BPlan As String, FullHTML As String, URL1 As String, Cut1 As String
    Dim FO As String, LO As String, Other1 As Long

    URL1 = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=AAPL+Profile"
    FullHTML = GetHTML(URL1)
    BPlan = "&nbsp;</th></tr></table><p>"
    FO = InStr(FullHTML, BPlan) + Len(BPlan)
    LO = InStr(FO, FullHTML, "<")
    Cut1 = Left(FullHTML, LO)
    Cut1 = Right(Cut1, FO - LO)

    Debug.Print Cut1
    'WB5.Cells(1, 1).Value = Cut1

End Sub

Function GetHTML(URL As String) As String
    Dim HTML As String
    Dim htmlBDY As New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .Send
        htmlBDY.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        GetHTML = htmlBDY.body.outerHTML
    End With
End Function
```

The HTMLDocument being received in the `.responseText` is more than what you would expect if tapping Ctrl+U to View Source. To pass back the source as a string from your function, you must resolve it down to a simple string.

Comment: for the line where you declare htmlBDY, my program says "user defined type not defined'

Comment: Go to the VBE's Tools ► References scroll down and put a checkmark beside Microsoft HTML Object Library.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable defining section is the issue. You need to tell what type it is before the comma (it's not used as English).

See below, if you don't specify the type, it's **Empty**.

[image: Dim Issue]